# Requests blocked in windows 7

Tags: python, windows, python-requests

I am trying to run a REST request in windows 7 but it is not executed from the python code below.

The code works in ubuntu, but doesn't windows 7:

```
def get_load_names(url='http://<ip>:5000/loads_list'):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        jData = json.loads(response.content)
        print(jData)
    else:
        print('error', response)
```

Also if I paste the url in the  browser, I see the request output. So I assume there is something to do with the firewall.

I created rules to open the port 5000 for input and output, but no luck so far.

Comment: What is the status_code and the response returned by your sample code ?

Comment: in windows is 504

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a very specific reason for writing your own error handling, you should use the built-in `raise_for_status()`

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get('http://<ip>:5000/loads_list')
response.raise_for_status()

jData = json.loads(response.text)
print(jData)
```

This will hopefully raise an informative error message that you can deal with.